# Combining both INNER and OUTER JOIN on two tables

Tags: sql

i have two tables, each with table_name and column_name in Oracle. I tried to join on the table_name but want to have left outer join on the column_names. I tried all means but failed to do write a correct one. please advise.

```
Table A and B
------------------
table_name
column_name
```

so, table A will have the entries;

```
table_name, column_name
AAA, Col1
AAA, Col2
AAA, col3
```

while table B will have the entries;

```
table_name, column_name
AAA, Col1
AAA, col2
```

ideally, the sql is somewhat like this;

```
select A.TABLE_NAME, A.COLUMN_NAME, B.COLUMN_NAME 
from 
cert2_all_tab_columns   A,
ITF_SYNAPSE B 
WHERE 
A.TABLE_NAME = B.TABLE_NAME AND
A.COLUMN_NAME (+)= B.COLUMN_NAME AND
 A.TABLE_NAME='ABC'
```

so the desired result will be;

```
table_name, column_name_fromA, column_name_fromB
AAA, col1, col1
AAA, col2, col2
AAA, col3, null
```

Comment: Please share more details, like which database system you are using, the table structure, sample input data, and the expected output corresponding to that input data

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output. By the way, standard ANSI JOINS are better than magic with (+)

Comment: Even Oracle recommends to stop using the `(+)` operator for outer joins

Comment: i have edited my question and added in the desired output as well as the sample data in the table A and B.

Comment: *ideally, the sql is somewhat like this* - well, only if it was 1990: [Bad habbits](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 0):

You would simply use:

```
select a.table_name, a.column_name, b.column_name
from a left join
     b
     using (table_name, column_name);
```

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: thanks for your advice.
    
i cant get the value from the second table in the select and i hit into this issue when i tried to use alias; 
ORA-25154: column part of USING clause cannot have qualifier

Answer (score 0):

This query works. is my syntax correct?

```
select TABLE_NAME,C1, C2
from 
(SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_NAME AS C1 FROM A) A
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_NAME AS C2 FROM B) B
USING (TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME);
```